# Flag Cool Note Node ID

Tags: 7, views, flags

I am using [Flagcoolnote](http://drupal.org/project/flagcoolnote) module to get some information from user while flagging the node via webform. It is working fine. But the problem is the webform submissions don't show any reference to node the user has flagged like node_id, title etc.

I had gone through the link:http://drupal.org/node/1524430, which says that issue has been resolved and support has been provided, but I am not finding as how can I create view that shows the user submitted data while flagging, with relation with flagged node.

Please suggest.

-- Thanks for your time.